# Evaluate null cast with reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection, null-cast

Given a null cast:

```
var result = MyMethod( (Foo) null );
```

Is it possible to use this extra information inside the method with reflection?

**EDIT:**
The method's signature is something like:

```
object MyMethod( params object[] args )
{
  // here I would like to see that args[0] is (was) of type Foo
}
```

Comment: Exactly how do you mean?

Comment: What precisely do you want to use and in what exact method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahh... you edited...

I suspect the closest you'll get is generics:

```
object MyMethod<T>( params T[] args ) {...}
```

(and look at `typeof(T)`)

But that assumes all the `args` are the same. Other than that; no. Every null is the same as every other (`Nullable<T>` aside), and you cannot tell the variable type.

---

Original reply:

Do you mean overload resolution?

```
object result = someType.GetMethod("MyMethod",
        new Type[] { typeof(Foo) })
        .Invoke(someInstance, new object[] { null });
```

(where `someInstance` is `null` for static methods, and `someType` is the `Type` that has the `MyMethod` method)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No

I'm guessing you got something like this:

```
class Foo : Bar{}
```

Since you've got:

```
object MyMethod(param object[] values);
```

There's no way to do this. You could use a null object pattern to accomplish this:

```
class Foo : Bar
{
 public static readonly Foo Null=new Foo();
}
```

and then call with **Foo.Null** instead of null. Your MyMethod could then check for the static instance and act accordingly:

```
object MyMethod(param object[] values
{
 if(values[0]==Foo.Null) ......
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the null object pattern - another idea.